# Bitcoin API - createmultisig - what is redeemScript?

Tags: development, bitcoin-core, api, multi-signature

The Bitcoin API call of `createmultisig` returns two parameters - `address` and `redeemScript`. What is the latter used for?

Answer (score 3):

To really understand this, you would need to [read the protocol specs](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script).  But I'll describe it briefly.

Each transaction contains a script.  In order to claim the bitcoins from a transaction (e.g.: you want to spend them in a new transaction) you have to provide whatever proof is described by the script.

Normally, the script is pretty much the same: the intended recipient has to provide a digital signature that proves they own the destination address.  But you can requires a lot of different kinds of proof: require more signatories, no proof at all, or require the claimant to solve a puzzle.

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with this: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0016.
Instead of providing the necessary scriptSignature when sending coins, you can just provide the hash of the script, and let the redeemer provide the actual script upon spending.